# Change manually to auto schedule

Tags: ms-project

I want to change the start date of a specific section in my project.

When I do that, it automatically changes the mode of this section from auto to manually schedule.

Is it possible to change the date and still remain on auto-schedule mode?

Answer (score 1):

From MSP 2010, typing a date directly into the Start column of a *Summary* task automatically converts it to manual mode.  Instead, double-click on the task and enter a "Start No Earlier Than" constraint on the Advanced tab of the Summary Task Information dialog.

Comment: (Note: constraints and logic on summary tasks are generally considered bad practice. Think about adding a sectional start milestone with a SNET constraint and suitable successor relationships to the other non-summary tasks in the section.)

Answer (score 0):

You have entered information into a summary task. A summary task simply 'rolls-up' or summarises its subtasks and all date information is calculated when auto-scheduled.
If you choose to over-write this calculated information, Microsoft Project will change the task mode to manual.